# searching for a word in a file using command argument? in python3, popping up no answers

Tags: file, python-3.x, command, arguments, line

trying to write a program that searches the dictionary file for words which start with the first command line argument, which is their stem but I'm getting nothing.

here's my code, what am I doing wrong?

```
import sys
import os

stem = str(sys.argv[1:])
searchline = open("american-english-insane")
for line in searchline:
 if line.startswith(stem):
  print(word)
```

On the other hand, this works and spits out hello, helloes, helloeing, etc... but it's not passed as a command line argument.

```
import sys
import os

stem = sys.argv[1:]
searchline = open("american-english-insane")
for line in searchline:
 if line.startswith('hello'):
  print(line)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a below snippet, which returns a string object

```
stem = sys.argv[1]
```